# Where does Microsoft store accounts on MacOS?

Tags: ms-office, microsoft

I installed Edge (chromium) on a work computer and created a new profile using the wrong MS account (personal). I deleted that profile, but when creating another, my personal account still shows as a suggestion for signing in.

At `~/Library/Application Support` I deleted all `Microsoft*` folders and deleted then reinstalled edge. I went to create a new profile and was *still* offered my personal account.

Where is this data located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data is saved in the Apple OS Keychain (on macOS and iOS and iPadOS) so on a Mac, access your keychain using the  Keychain Access app.

1. Find Keychain Access in Launchpad or spotlight
2. Launch it, then once opened, type "OneAuthAccount" into the search box

As of writing (2022-05-18), the entries are labeled like so `com.microsoft.oneauth.<random-characters>` under the **Name** column.

If there are several entries (of **Kind** "application password" specifically), unfortunately it is unclear which specific accounts they refer to. Unless you can correlate by time stamps showing when they were added, you'll just have to delete all then sign in with just those you want.