# Where does Microsoft Teams store its cached login credentials?

Tags: macos, preferences, ventura, microsoft, ms-teams

When I launch Teams.app (currently using beta 1.6.00.10052 on macOS 13.3.1) I am greeted with a login/auth popup containing **7 accounts**. I only currently use **2** of them. The others are related to test accounts that I used at some point in the distant past.

I've traced every file that Teams seems to touch from launch leading up to that window appearing using `eslogger`. I also traced the HTTP traffic with Proxyman. I still can't figure out where this data is coming from. I raised this question as an [issue](https://github.com/ItzLevvie/MicrosoftTeams-msinternal/issues/36) over on the MicrosoftTeams-msinternal GitHub but didn't get an answer.

[image: Teams login window]

How can I clear this cache or remove these accounts from the chooser?

**Update:** Thanks to bmike for the answer below—indeed it was the Keychain storing these credentials all along. Here's a one-liner that I ended up settling on that successfully reset them:

```bash
for svce in AdalCache OneAuthAccount; do security delete-generic-password -s $svce; done
```

Comment: It’s likely coming from the Teams (backend) server.  [Login to Teams via web](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/log-in) and see if those accounts appear.

Comment: Do you use ANY other Microsoft apps (Edge, Outlook, Office, Azure, Visual Studio, ...) on the Mac?

Comment: @bmike Yes, I use all of those. But, even after signing out of ALL of them (including the web as Allan suggested) the cached credentials do not disappear. They even persist if I disconnect the WiFi and Ethernet.

Comment: Correct - they use the keychain - I can't find the MS article, but will put in an answer. Feel free to edit my answer if you find just the item for your teams to clear this up. It's gonna be in the keychain almost 99% likely.

Comment: I think you have to log into your accounts (you don’t want to see any more) and remove the devices linked to them.  For example, I have both my personal and work MS accounts and they both show up on all my devices.  However, my third (personal) microsoft account doesn’t show up because I went in and deleted all of the associated devices.  Give that a shot.

Comment: I love that one liner to nuke the items surgically! - Well done, it will help us clean up some shared account / lab machines regularly.

Comment: I was facing this problem recently, removing keychaing records didnt worked for me and I just delete the folder at "~Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Teams". and it worket. (I came across to the solution while looking for another problem, one stone and two birds!  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/microsoft-teams-desktop-on-mac-stuck-in-login-loop/m-p/1341170/page/2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Microsoft uses the native keychain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441253/5472) to store your identity for their macOS / iOS / iPadOS apps. As long as you have a backup or know you can sign back in to your Microsoft account, there's no harm in deleting all Microsoft related entries from your keychain and then restarting / quitting all the apps (including background helpers) and then seeing if you cleared enough.

Search for the strings below in your keychain:

- ADAL
- OneAuthAccount
- Microsoft (especially com.microsoft items..)

Some Microsoft items are delivered by Apple as part of the system keychain and root certificates, so those should not be deleted, but a reinstall of macOS from recovery or backup will fix that and things don't break when people have deleted too much in my experience in the past.

Also in the past, ADALcache items were issues:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-for-mac-repeatedly-requesting-keychain-access-ced5a09c-3099-47cb-9190-e961bf63e240
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/sign-in/repeated-prompts-authentication (***THIS ONE IS VERY GOOD*** - describes how to use the keychain and how Microsoft uses it for Outlook which is very close to the implementation Teams used in 2022 and earlier)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v2-keychain-objc?tabs=objc (***very technical*** - explains how this all is engineered to use native Apple SDK / API / keychain idiom)

There's MSAL / ADAL / and legacy log in code shipped by Microsoft, so what worked in the past may not work now - use care googling on this topic / check versions of apps / and as always, a backup and **reading closely** the dialogs & warnings are key survival tactics that save you time later. If you have to reinstall macOS - none of your data or preferences will go bad - just try not to force delete root keychains (if macOS will even let you do that).